GLSL Getting a transparent border around my rectangle
I'm trying to create a shader which renders a rounded rectangle with a drop shadow.
This is my main fragment shader
        vec2 center = (u_model_size.xy - vec2(100, 100)) * 0.5;
        vec2 u_shadow_offset = vec2(50, 50);

        float crop = rounded_rectangle(v_position.xy - center, center, u_radius);
        float shadow_crop = rounded_rectangle(v_position.xy - center - u_shadow_offset, center, u_radius);

        shadow_crop = smoothstep(-1.0, 1.0, shadow_crop);
        crop = smoothstep(-1.0, 1.0, crop);

        if (crop == 1.0 && shadow_crop < 1.0) {
            gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), crop);
        } else {
            gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, vec4(0.0), crop);
        }

Fragment function for calculating SDF
        // https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions2d.htm
        float rounded_rectangle(in vec2 p, in vec2 b, in vec4 r)
        {
            r.xy = (p.x > 0.0) ? r.xy : r.zw;
            r.x  = (p.y > 0.0) ? r.x  : r.y;
            vec2 q = abs(p) - b + r.x;
            return min(max(q.x, q.y), 0.0) + length(max(q, 0.0)) - r.x;
        }

u_model_size is a uniform vec2 which has the size of the available rendering space/the size of the model we are running the shader on.
v_position is a varying vec4 which has the position of the vertex being rendered.
Now I have two issues, with the first being the biggest issue:

There is a transparent border around the area where the main rectangle meets the drop shadow. It appears white here because if the background colour, but it is transparent. .
Both the dropshadow and the rectangle has very sharp edges (visible in the image). When I try to make the edges smoother using a bigger upper and lower bounds for smoothstep, it ends up creating a blur which is desirable for the drop shadow but not for the main rectangle.

But I can only apply the smoothstep on the main rectangle and not on the dropshadow no matter what I try. If I change gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), crop); to gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), shadow_crop);, it makes the dropshadow the same colour as the main rectangle with the outline being of the colour of the dropshadow. If anyone can explain why that happens, I will be really grateful. 
If possible, I want to change the upper and lower bounds of smoothstep to give a softer/blurrier apperance to the drop shadow.



What am I doing wrong?
ADDITIONAL DETAILS
There is an underlying shader which is giving the green gradient (I'm chaining shaders) but it's quite simple.
Main Vertex function
        v_gradient_done = dot(a_position.xy, u_gradient_direction) / dot(u_model_size, u_gradient_direction);

Main Fragment function
        float gradient_done = v_gradient_done;
        gl_FragColor = mix(u_gradient_left, u_gradient_right, gradient_done);


Have your enabled blending and set the blend equation?
